# Родитель-воспитатель: дефис или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, дефис-тире

"Родитель(-)воспитатель воспитательной группы". Здесь тире или дефис? Я думаю, что дефис. Но сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире - это пунктуационный знак, а дефис - орфографический. В вашем случае, насколько я понимаю, речь идет о сочетании с однословными приложением, следующим за определяемым словом. В таких случаях употребляется дефис (Лопатин В.В. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации; Орфография, § 120).

Answer (score 3):

Боже, канцелярит расцветает пышным цветом... Пойди пойми, что они хотели сказать.

Тире или дефис - это от смысла зависит.
Может, конечно, быть, что речь идёт об однословном приложении, т. е. некоей должности, "родителе-воспитателе" (по принципу "дивана-кровати" или "ракеты-носителя").
Но не менее вероятно, что это лозунг "Родитель - воспитатель воспитательной группы!"
В любом случае мозги выносит.

Comment: Да, русский язык - это же сплошная философия!)